# String is empty in my class Java

Tags: android, string, class

I have a problem with the values of my class. In the pintln the value of partida_club is ok but in this.partida_club is empty.

If I write in partida_tipo = "car", this is Ok.
The abstract: In the example partida_club not working and partida_tipo working ok

```
public class datos_partidas {

     protected String partida_club;
     protected String partida_tipo;

    public datos_partidas(String partida_club, String partida_tipo){
         super();

         System.out.println(partida_club); // Print "Son Muntaner"

         this.partida_club = partida_club; // This return empty
         this.partida_tipo = "car"; // This return "car"
    }

}
```

**Call**

```
partida = new datos_partidas(
                            partidas.get(i).getPartida_club(),
                            partidas.get(i).getPartida_tipo());
                    arraydir.add(partida);
```

Comment: Can you show us how you call `datos_partidas()`? Also avoid using the same name to avoid confusions. You can use _ prefix before your constructor variables. Like `(String _partida_club, String _partida_tipo)`

Comment: Added the call to datos_partidas

Comment: Well that's odd. You're calling a constructor with 8 params and you 're showing us a constructor with only 2.

Comment: you have initialized your object with 8 parameters but you have posted constructor with two parameters to us!!

Comment: Sorry, everything have 8 parameters. I have put two not to put all code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class datos_partidas {

     protected String partida_club;
     protected String partida_tipo;

    public datos_partidas(String partida_club, String partida_tipo){
         super();

         //the value is still not given to partida_club  
         System.out.println(partida_club); 

         this.partida_club = partida_club;
         this.partida_tipo = "car"; // partida_tipo is now "car"
    }

}
```

The `partida_club` is empty because somewhere in your code you are making it empty or haven't assigned any value yet.

The `partida_tipo` is not empty because you are assigning the string "car" directly to it.

You can check by providing the values to the method like -

```
//Now partida_club  and partida_tipo contains strings
datos_partidas("15sep", "car");
```

So its simple -

If you provide empty value, the same will go to the constructor else not.

**UPDATE:**

As I see looking in your code, you may have passed something like -

```
partida_club =  partidas.get(i).getPartida_club()
partida_tipo =  partidas.get(i).getPartida_tipo()
```

Here the problem is - `partidas.get(i).getPartida_club()` is having nothing so `partida_club` is empty.

Try to print the value of  `partidas.get(i).getPartida_club()` and you will see that it's blank.

**UPDATE:**

```
public class datos_partidas {

     protected String partida_club;
     protected String partida_tipo;

    public datos_partidas(String partida_club, String partida_tipo){
         super();

         //the value is still not given to partida_club  
         System.out.println(partida_club); 

         this.partida_club = partida_club; //the value is now given to partida_club  
         this.partida_tipo = "car"; // partida_tipo is now "car"

         //this should not be blank
         System.out.println(partida_club); 
    }

}
```

Comment: partidas.get(i).getPartida_club() is not empty, when I do a println, have value

Comment: @JordiSalom - You didn't got the point. The `partidas.get(0).getPartida_club()` may not be empty. The `partidas.get(1).getPartida_club()` may not be empty. But the latest value of i that goes to this method is empty. If it is 5 then `partidas.get(5).getPartida_club()` is empty.

Comment: //the value is still not given to partida_club  
         System.out.println(partida_club);. Your comment is incorrect because the println print a value ("Son Muntaner").

Comment: @JordiSalom - The final value is overwritten with the previous value. You need to print all values in a loop for each i to know all values that are passed on to the constructor. Trace it with a logic and flow.

Comment: @JordiSalom - Or check my recent update if that is what you want.

Comment: System.out.println(partida_club); // This is not blank. It have value.

Answer (score 0):

First you call System.out.println, then - init. Try this:

```
   public class datos_partidas {

   protected String partida_club;
   protected String partida_tipo;

   public datos_partidas(String partida_club, String partida_tipo){
         super();


         this.partida_club = partida_club;
         this.partida_tipo = "car";
         System.out.println(partida_club);
    }

}
```

Also when you call datos_partidas(String, String), you string is not empty ?

Comment: Is empty if I write System.out.println(partida_club); later of this.partida_tipo = "car";

Answer (score 0):

Change your function so it looks like this:

```
public class datos_partidas {

     protected String partida_club;
     protected String partida_tipo;

    public datos_partidas(String _partida_club, String _partida_tipo){
         super();

         System.out.println(_partida_club);

         this.partida_club = _partida_club;
         this.partida_tipo = "car";
    }

}
```

This should work if you're calling the constructor correctly.

Comment: Not working, is empty. In the println _partida_club is not empty but in this.partida_club = _partida_club yes.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you familiarized with the concept of constructor? If the _partida_club is not empty than this code is working as intended and you're setting the partida_club value of your datos_partidas to the same as _partida_club. As intended.

Comment: Exactly, in the println is not empty. I integrate this in this.partida_club and not read nothing.
Later the return of constructor I introduce the values in array. Is correct? arraydir.add(partida); Adapter_listaPartidas adapter = new Adapter_listaPartidas(this, arraydir);

Answer (score -1):

firsty I firmly believe that you have a tremendous mistake in your constructor.You should write:

```
 this.partida_club = partida_club;
 this.partida_tipo = partida_tipo;
```

Then if you wanna be sure if your variables have been taken a good idea is to use a JOptionPane for instance.Another way is to write this:

```
public String toString()
{
  return "partida club"+" "+"partida_club+"partida tipo" +"\n" ;
}
```